# How do you add a UIImageViews under a UITextView (the UITextView spans entire screen)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitextview

My UITextView has a description, but at the bottom of it, I want to add images underneath the last line of text. How do I do that?

```
UITextView* description = [[UITextView alloc] init];
description.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
description.text = [self.dict valueForKey:@"description"];
description.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[self.view addSubview:description];
```

EDITED: The text is not editable. What I really want to do looks like an app in the Apple App Store. After scrolling to the bottom of the description, there's a scrollable view of screenshots. I want to implement the same thing as that.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a text view where the user is can edit the text? If so, if they edit, what is the interplay between the edits and the images? Or are you just displaying a long body of text in which you want to include some images, too. If the latter, you could use a UIWebview instead. Describe your desired user experience in a little more detail and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're asking for, but look into [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (a subclass of UIScrollView). A tableview might work best as you can add your textview to one cell, and then the image views in subsequent cells. If you can post additional details, I might be able to help more.